# Slow Simulated Typing Speed in Ubuntu When Using Nonprintable Characters

Tags: xdotool, evdev

I’ve encountered an issue in Ubuntu that seems to have persisted since at least version `20.04`. The problem appears to be related to the handling of nonprintable characters such as `\n`, `\t`, and `\e`.

Here’s a Python snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```py
import sys
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key

keyboard = Controller()
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
keyboard.type(message.replace('\n', r'\n'))
```

In the above code, if I remove the `.replace('\n', r'\n')` part, the script runs significantly slower. It seems as though the presence of newlines (and other nonprintable characters) slows down the execution.

This issue isn’t limited to Python or the `pynput` library. I’ve been able to reproduce it using `xlib`, and it appears to be the underlying cause of slow performance in `libxdo` (and `xdotool`), `pyautogui`, and similar tools on Ubuntu.

Interestingly, this problem doesn’t occur on Arch Linux.

My question is: can anyone identify and explain why this is happening? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.